# PHP simplexlsxgen issue displaying HTML special characters

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am exporting some data into an excel by using [simplexlsxgen](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen) . My data has a value `<<NEW>>` and I am having a trouble displaying it.

In my code I prepared it in `htmlspecialchars("<<NEW>>")`, which will work if I want to display it in the browser page, but when it gets exported in an excel `$xlsx->saveAs($fullFilePath)` the data somehow will become `&lt;&lt;NEW&gt;&gt;`. If I simply prepare it as `"<<NEW>>"` nothing will be displayed.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
$excelArr = [
    ['DOC', 'DOCDATE'],
    ['<<NEW>>', '05/01/2023']
];

$xlsx = $this->simplexlsxgen->fromArray($excelArr);
$xlsx->saveAs('/');
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT OF ABOVE**

[image]

Since in `$excelArr` the value `<<NEW>>` is simply written as it is, it displays an empty cell when exported in excel. Due to this, as what I mentioned above, I tried to use `htmlspecialchars("<<NEW>>")` instead which I thought would work but it will display `&lt;&lt;NEW&gt;&gt;` in the excel cell.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is **only** used for output to a browser, and it seems it's doing its job. Don't use it if you're saving to an Excel file.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular okay thank you for the clarification. But is there a way to display it in excel? Since I could not display them by simply writing `"<<NEW>>"` when generating it.

Comment: You've not posted sufficient code to debug this.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I have updated my question. Hope it's sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw strings to insert tags
https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen#raw-strings